# Find A Middle Date Between Two Dates in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using a D3.js scatterplot to show amount of works according to time periods. I would like to place points at the middle date between the beginning and ending dates for each period. The data I have looks like this:

```
period, amount, startDate, endDate
1, 5, 26/11/1982, 2/6/1989
2, 6, 2/6/1989,2/1/1990
3, 11, 2/01/1990,20/6/1999
```

I tried mapping points on the graph using:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(new Date(d.endDate)) - xScale(new Date(d.startDate)) * 0.5 })
```

But this doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The middle point between two given points is:

```
middleX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
```

In your case:

```
d => {
  const xFrom = xScale(new Date(d.startDate));
  const xTo = xScale(new Date(d.endDate));
  return (xFrom + xTo) / 2;
}
```